# Chrome headless print-to-pdf doesn't render images

Tags: google-chrome-headless

I am trying to write a script to output a lot of markdown pages to PDF using Chrome's headless mode.   My current command is:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome  --headless  
  --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw  --disable-gpu 
  --print-to-pdf="index.pdf" http://localhost:8080/#!index.md
```

The resulting PDF file seems to render as it would be shown except for the images.   What I get in the PDF file is a link to the image instead of the image itself.

When I run the `--screenshot` option I do get the pictures you would expect in the resulting image file.

I think the reason is that it has something to do with the page being rendered with MDwiki, which does a lot of client-side work to convert markdown to HTML.   But when I try to use the `--virtual-time-budget` option Chrome errors out with a message about multiple tables only allowed if debugger is enabled.

Any suggestions for what next to try?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is an node package that takes care of this: chrome-headless-render-pdf.  There isn't much documentation but it works.  Check out:

```
npm docs chrome-headless-render-pdf
```